# How to approach a problem with infinite solutions

Tags: machine-learning, algorithm

Think Angry Birds kind of game. You need to hit a target at some point by adjusting angle and power. There is infinite number of parabolas that will solve this problem.

My problem is not exactly that but similar, it also has infinite number of solutions. Could anyone please suggest how do I approach this kind of problems using Machine Learning?

Comment: Best way is to apply regularization to make it one solution. For example add requirements of minimum energy and/or minimum time, length etc. or make solution maximally close to initial approximation

Comment: well doesnt matter if it has million solutions, you just need to find one. If youre asking how to optimize in your domain, you need to be more specific so people can help you out. (there is no general answer to the problem you posed)

Comment: Functionally, though, it's not infinite, in that the number arcs are limited by the finite limits of the system.  So there may be a large number of parabolas that can be expressed in-game, but not an infinite number.